# php mysql sort by number of rows descending

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, distinct

can you help me

```
$sql="select * from table1 where id='1,2,3,4'";
{
 $sql2="select distinct column1 from table2 where column2='".$row['id']."' and left(date,10) BETWEEN '".$date_from."' AND '".$date_to."'";
 }
```

I need to sort **$sql** by number of rows descending for **$sql2** by **id**

Comment: Why would you wrap the second query in `{}`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want the results from `$sql` ordered by number of rows found by `$sql2` for each row in `$sql`. This join should do that, it joins table2 and orders by the count, descending.

```sql
SELECT t1.id
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id=t2.column2
WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4)                     -- should it really be = '1,2,3,4'?
  AND LEFT(date,10) BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY COUNT(DISTINCT t2.column1) DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c5955/2).

Comment: This is exactly what I want http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16536571/sql1-to-get-names-and-sql2-to-get-impressions-i-need-to-sort-names-by-impressio

Comment: @mohammed I'm not quite sure what's wrong with the answer above. If you gave feedback instead of starting a new question, it'd be easier to answer.