# sql1 to get names and sql2 to get Impressions, I need to sort names by Impressions

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Hello I have this Project and I need to help me

```
$sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM table1 where column1='1'";

    $total_Results = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql1));

    $total_Results = $total_Results[num];

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql1))

        {

$sql2="select distinct column1 from table2 where column2='".$row['id']."' and left(date,10) BETWEEN '".$datefrom."' AND '".$dateto."'";

$res=mysql_query($sql2);

}
```

sql1 to get names and sql2 to get Impressions, I need to sort names by Impressions

---

name          |   Impressions DESC

---

A             |         10

B             |         8

C             |          7

---

or

---

name           |    Impressions ASC

---

C              |        7

B              |         8

A              |         10

---

Thanks for your attention

Comment: What is the question ? or what is the problem ?

Comment: Same as [this question you asked yesterday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506952/php-mysql-sort-by-number-of-rows-descending)?

Comment: Yes, this is to clarify what I want.

Comment: $sql1 = "SELECT COUNT(*) as num FROM table1 where column1='1'"; This query return the count from table. $row['id'] will return undefined index error check your queries..

Comment: How sql1 can give you names as output while you are just taking count(*) from this query????

Comment: yes yes Sorry,  $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM table1 where column1='1'";

Comment: but in this case  $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM table1 where column1='1'" you will lose the count you have to get select all the fields you need + the count

Comment: yes I am Understand, now I need to get Results of sql2 and sort by the Most results

Comment: The method you are using the perform your SQL actions is quickly becoming outdated.  While this won't solve your immediate problem, you should learn [PDO](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/) and stop using the old `mysql_connect` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll add almost the same answer as on your previous question. You can do it all in a join instead of separate queries;

```sql
SELECT t1.id as name, COUNT(DISTINCT t2.column1) Impressions
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2
  ON t1.id=t2.column2
WHERE t1.column1 = 1
  AND LEFT(date,10) BETWEEN '2013-01-01' AND '2013-12-31'
GROUP BY t1.id
ORDER BY Impressions DESC
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/02300/3).

Answer (score 0):

You need to select id too in your sql1 query

```
$sql1 = "SELECT id,COUNT(*) as num FROM table1 where column1='1'";
```

otherwise you won't get id in the result or you can select all the fields + count (*)

```
 $sql1 = "SELECT *,COUNT(*) as num FROM table1 where column1='1'";
```